# Different performance with Intel XDK

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

I use Intel XDK to develop apps with HTML and Cordova. I use jQuery Mobile. My question is: Why if I debug app with XDK and an Android device I have a very good performance, and if I compile app into an .apk, same code works very very slow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you build the app with the usual Android build, while the App Preview uses the Crosswalk Android build for the preview, which is much faster for Android < 4.3.

Build your app with 'Crosswalk for Android', you'll get the same performance. :)